# Excel plotting airfoil curves from a paper, faulty polynom?

Tags: excel, plot, curve

I'm trying to plot airfoil camber lines in excel, given the polynomial and some constants.

Here is the given data, the final to reach is on the right top, with the (x,y) coordinates being used to create a CAD model of a wing that will be used for a 3-bladed wind turbine rotor.

[image: Here is the given data, the final to reach is on the right top]

For the moment I get this:

[image: For the moment I get this]

Is there a fault in the given polynomial?

Comment: Can you add some text that explains what's in the pictures? I can't for the life of me read what you've put in that first image: just write out the parts that matter for people to read, and ignore everything else: what's some of your sample data, what's the formula you're using, what's the result, what _should_ the result be, what are your guesses as to why, and what have you already looked at in order to try to fix things?

Comment: Hello, in table 1 you have two rows ( in row 1, the only data used are column 2 and 3, x'LE (x coordinate location of the leading edge of the airfoil, and y'LE (y coordinate of the leading edge of the airfoil). In row 2 you find 4 columns with constants a0 a1 a2 a3 a4. The z' (mm) is the location of the airfoil c along the z axis (going into the screen with y and x axis the plane of your screen showing the airfoil curves), in total there are 6 airfoil camber lines (see the 6 curves)

Comment: fig 4.5 is the correct outcome (or suggested, hoping the data is correct)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans if something is not clear, don't hesitate to contact me, thanks in advance!

Comment: that is not how Stackoverflow works. Please take a moment to take the [tour] and then read up on ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask), because it's on you to make sure your post has the information it needs, and to make sure it doesn't have the information that it doesn't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the authors reported the *a* parameters in reverse order. What was reported as a0 is in fact a3, reported a1 is a2, reported a2 is a1 and reported a3 is a0. To give a specific example, the parameters when z' = 10 mm should be

```
a0 = -0.8E-03
a1 = -8.44E-01
a2 =  2.99E-02
a3 = -3E-04
```

and the equation when z' = 10 mm should be

```
y' = yLE + [-0.8E-03]*(x'-xLE)^0 + [-8.44E-01]*(x'-xLE)^1 + [2.99E-02]*(x'-xLE)^2 + [-3E-04]*(x'-xLE)^3
```

Note that the parameters as reported are multiplied by scale factors (e.g. 10^4) and you need to divide the reported values by those scale factors to get the true values.

Here's my graph of the airfoil profiles
[image]

This could have happened if the authors used Excel's `LINEST` function to do data fitting, because `LINEST` reports curve fit parameters in high-to-low order (a[n], a[n-1], ... a[2], a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r451r.jpg), a[0]). To me this is ordering counter-intuitive and can lead to confusion.

Hope that helps